# Deserialize DateTime field in json file using Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, json, pandas, datetime, parsing

I am parsing a json file using Pandas in Python. There is a field called DateTime with the following string in it: `1581251737000`. Does anybody know the format of this DateTime field so that I can parse it using the pandas.to_datetime() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is by using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

x = "1581251737000"
pd.to_datetime(x, unit="ms")

#Output
Timestamp('2020-02-09 12:35:37')
```

You can use strftime to convert this to your desired format:

```
pd.to_datetime(x, unit="ms").strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

#Output
'2020/02/09'
```

Answer (score 0):

this is called `epoch timestamp` in milliseconds format, you can remove trailing there zeros and convert it to readable datetime like this:

```py
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1581251737))
```

Answer (score 0):

While using pandas, you can define your custom format to aid the `pd.to_datetime` function like this:

```
pd.to_datetime('13000101', format='%Y%m%d', errors='ignore')
```

In your case, you will first have to convert this timestamp into a date-time stamp by providing the units argument as `ms` which I'm guessing is true in your case.
I'd recommend you define your own format to avoid any trailing zeros

By default, pandas uses `YYYY MM DD HH MM SS MSMSMS`

Check out the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)